# Commerce Module - Changing product in a display node makes the image revert back to default

Tags: 7, commerce

I am having some trouble with the D7 Commerce module.

I have a t-shirt product type with three fields; 'shirt size','shirt color' and a image. Each shirt that is a different size but the same color uses the same image. Shirts with different colors use a different images.

For one product display node, I select a small,medium,large shirt size for both white and black colors. So 6 products total for one node. This way the user can select color and size for the shirt on a single page.

When a user selects a different color the image changes to that color version of the shirt, which is great. However whenever the user chooses a different size after already picking a non-default color, the image reverts back the the default color+image. So the user would have to select the color again. Or
even worse, not realize that the color changed and order the wrong color.

How can I make it so the color+image doesn't change back to default when a different size is chosen?

Comment: so I figured out if I put the shirt color field above the shirt size field in the product type (manage field tab), then the image doesn't change, but the shirt size changes to default. So now a customer has a good chance of ordering the wrong size if they pick a size first then a color. 

Question becomes, how can I turn off these dependencies the list have on each other?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Haven't found a solution to this, but a workaround I am using is to disable the 'enable as attribute' of both list fields, this makes it so there is only one list in the add to cart form. The list will have a option for each product that the node references, so if you have a lot of products, this can create a long list.

To do this, go to producttype > manage fields > edit (list field) and turn off 'enable this field to function as an attribute field on Add to Cart forms.' Then save. You have to do this for each list field.

I will edit if I find a direct solution.